# How can I login to a website with python3.2 urllib?

Tags: python, authentication, urllib

How can I login to sites like facebook or google with python 3.2 urllib?
Please give me some examples.

Actually, I want to retrieve my photos or some data like replies or articles written by others.
But I can not get through these sites without logging in.

Comment: If possible, use their APIs, which will save you a lot of pain. If you can't do what you want, try a library like mechanize, but be aware that they're both complex sites which aren't easy to access from a script. You might want to look at accessing the mobile versions of the sites, which are often simpler.